# .net (C#) MVC with the OCR and extract oly the specific word to store it into database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I seraching for a free .Net (MVC) library that i can use to scan from a document scanner and then OCR the document so i can get the text from it to save in a database. Like for example, I scan an insurance document. Then I only want to get the name and the insurance id and store it into database.

Answer (score 0):

There's Microsoft Cognitive Services Computer Vision that can do OCR, you can use it with API calls or with its .NET client library (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/csharp-print-text)

It's free under 5000 calls/month (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/)